# Public "using" = decltype(<private>)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, language-lawyer, decltype

In the following (minimized) code, I have a public `using` declaration that is referring to `decltype(something_private)`: `using Foo = decltype(something_private<T>)`.

On Clang but not GCC this does not compile because of it being private.

Questions:

1. What is an elegant solution if I do not want to make `func<T>()` public.
2. Where in the C++ standard (C++11) does is backup Clang to be correct here?

The below code fails with the following error code on Clang (3.9 - 7.0) but builds on GCC (4.8.4 - 8.2):

```
class A {
private:
    template <class T>
    static auto func() -> T; // The actual return type is much
       // more complicated, so `using Foo = T` would not work.

public:
    template <class T>
    using Foo = decltype(func<T>());
};

int main(int, char**) {
    A::Foo<int> y;
    return y;
}
```

Clang 7.0 output:

```
<source>:10:24: error: 'func' is a private member of 'A'
  using Foo = decltype(func<T>());
                       ^~~~~~~

<source>:14:7: note: in instantiation of template type alias 'Foo' requested here
   A::Foo<int> y;
          ^

<source>:6:15: note: declared private here
  static auto func() -> T;
              ^

1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

https://godbolt.org/z/zD4Hk5

Comment: https://wg21.link/cwg1554

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't looked at the standard for citation, but have a workaround for you.  Because this works, it makes me think clang just has a bug.  When the function is directly in A, it treats the type alias as if it were in the context of the caller, but moving the function into a struct solves that. *Meh.* I've done a lot of g++ / clang porting lately and while I didn't run into this specifically, it smelled of some things I encountered.

```cpp
class A {
private:
    struct X {
        template <class T>
        static auto func() -> T;
    };
  
public:
    template <class T>
    using Foo = decltype(X::func<T>());
};

void bar() {
     A::Foo<int> y;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ozIS-r

UPDATE: added citation.

I think this directly answers your question, and that clang is wrong here.

> N4778 (the latest I found), 10.8/p4 (pg 259) ... [Note: Because access control applies to names, if access control is applied to a typedef name, only the accessibility of the typedef name itself is considered. The accessibility of the entity referred to by the typedef is not considered.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! When asking for clarification with reference to the standard, I've been biased in the past where GCC is overly permissive, while Clang is normally strictly adhering to the standard. This is the first time, where I am not sure whether Clang might be too strict. That's why I am still additionally for an answer in this respect.

Comment: @Unapiedra, I have those concerns too, but struct X is also private to A, and A::X::func() is still private to bar().  It should consistently work or not work, I would think.  In any case, I found a citation that is satisfactory to me, and updated my answer to include it.